# Movie where the "happy place" isn't true but instead old machines are broken down for food

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can't find a movie I used to see. It was about girl-machines who thought that they would go to the "happy place" when they finished their service. One of them meets a guy who tells her this isn't true. He takes her to a factory to show her that old machines are sent there instead of the "happy place". It turns out that old machines are actually being utilized to become food for new ones.

Comment: Animated or live-action? When would it have been released?

Answer (score 30):

This might be the "Neo Seoul, 2144" chapter of [*Cloud Atlas*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1371111/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (2012).  Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Atlas_(film)):

> In 2144, Sonmi-451 is a "fabricant", a human cloned for slave labor, kept as a fast food server in a dystopian Neo Seoul. She is exposed to ideas of rebellion by another fabricant, Yoona-939. After Yoona is killed, Sonmi is rescued by rebel Commander Hae-Joo Chang, who exposes Sonmi to the banned writings of Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn and a film version of Cavendish's experience. Hae-Joo eventually introduces her to the leader of the rebel movement, and shows her that clones are recycled into food for other clones.

A couple of stills of Sonmi and Yoona from the movie:

[image: Yoona conspiring with Sonmi]
[image: Fabricants eating]

You can also see some scenes of Sonmi-451 in the extended trailer:

There's another glimpse of Sonmi and Chang at 2:37.  (Thanks to InvisibleTrihedron for the pointer.)

Comment: The extended [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWnAqFyaQ5s) includes a few scenes that show Sonmi-451.

Comment: Incidentally, for those who may be intrigued by this description: _Cloud Atlas_ is a complex movie, challenging to watch. Blink and you'll miss something. The book it was based on had an interesting organization: the first half of story 1, then the first halves of stories 2, 3, 4, 5, then the complete story 6, then the last halves of stories 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1. All the stories are interrelated by reincarnation and the book spans several centuries. The director of the film chose to rearrange the stories in smaller segments so that the viewer has to follow all six stories simultaneously.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron Which (the rearrangement) I think is a major problem with the film because the stories become much less intertwined than promised.

Comment: The first time I watched it, I had to turn off my left brain and just let my right brain comprehend it by gestalt. That worked a lot better than trying to follow the stories individually, and I think that may have been the director's intention.

Comment: Maybe the answer should be extended to explain why the "happy place" idea is a match here: The sentence "shows her that clones are recycled into food for other clones" skips the bit about the clones believing they have to serve for a number of years, and then undergo the ceremony of "xultation", about which they believe is the moment they get released into freedom.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!! You're the best :)

Comment: @KatarzynaP Seems like you set up a different account to post this response from the one you used to ask the original question. If you [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), you'll be able to formally mark this answer as correct, as well as comment freely without needing to post answers.